# Should I make the class static or non-static for the following case?

Tags: c#, class-design, static-methods

I have a `class` which has the purpose of providing file operations i.e. providing functionality to create the file, read, write and rewrite to the file. So, the main constituent of the class is functions.

However, there is one functionality where I am using a `Timer` to make the `thread` wait for one second. So, basically I have an `AutoResetEvent` and `Timer` working in conjunction.

Now, since we have to register the `Timer_Elapsed` callback to the `Timer`, we need a place to do it. Since the class is `static`, I can use a `static constructor` to do that but this makes me think whether the class should be static at first place.

I am confused whether to make the class static or non-static as it is mostly about giving simple functionality but at the same time `Timer` and `AutoResetEvent` have become kind of state elements of the class. I would appreciate suggestions.

**Edit**
Reason why I am using a Timer is:

I am trying to synchronize file access between two processes by using `FileShare.None`. In order to do that I am in a loop to reattempt to gain access to the FileStream for which I have to wait 1 second each iteration. I am developing functionality in legacy code so I want to avoid `Thread.Sleep`. Also I know that a `mutex` would be a better option to synchronize access to a file but I cannot use it as I have so many such files that creating a `mutex` for each is not preferred (I am asked to not create mutex).

Comment: Generally speaking, I prefer to chose the singleton approach than having a static class so it can be injected (as an interface) and mocked more easily for tests and your logic code isn't tightly coupled to your persistence/data access layer.

Comment: Try to move the functionality with the timer and the AutoResetEvent into a separate class which is not static.

Comment: @JeromeJ I am dealing with legacy code and unit tests are far from reality....I also think that singleton injection is best but since I am with legacy do you think static would be fine?

Comment: @helb Would you then inject the class object with timer code using a static constructor in the File operations class?

Comment: No, you can't pass arguments to the static constructor. You may pass it to an Init() method or just instantiate it in the static contructor.

Comment: Consider why a Timer and AutoResetEvent are in a class whose purpose is to perform File I/O -- this sounds like a violation of the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html) to me.   I agree with helb's suggestion of splitting them out into separate classes.

Comment: I'm unsure about your reasoning to avoid `Thread.Sleep` (as per the comments on the answer) Are you expecting to run multithreaded? If no, then your single thread will always block for a second, regardless of how you do it. If yes, then sleeping one thread will not impact the other thread. So in either case, I don't see a reason to discount `Thread.Sleep` as a viable solution.

Comment: @Flater I get your point and I am going ahead with `Thread.Sleep`

Comment: @NavjotSingh: I've posted an answer with the content of my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Turning this comment into an answer as OP accepted it as a viable answer.*

---

I'm unsure about your reasoning to avoid `Thread.Sleep` (as per the comments on the answer) Are you expecting to run multithreaded?

- If no, then your single thread will always block for a second, regardless of how you do it.
- If yes, then sleeping one thread will not impact the other thread.

So in either case, I don't see a reason to discount `Thread.Sleep` as a viable solution.

---

In response to your comment:

> @Flater yeah agree, but when we do Thread.Sleep we make the thread not reusable.

Note that `await Task.Delay(1000);` works equally well as `Thread.Sleep(1000)`. However, if you are limited to a single thread, this can lead to your sleeping task to not be picked up for longer than a second.

Essentially, when you delay, the thread will look for another task to work on. However, it will not look back at the original task until its current task is being delayed as well. If the new task is long-running, then it may take some time for your original task to be picked up again.

But when you sleep (instead of delay), then the current tasks *remains* the current task, nothing else will be pickd up in the mean time, and the thread will resume after exactly a second.

Maybe that's okay, maybe it's not. I don't know enough about your circumstances to make that call. But consider which one is more appropriate for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I've read you mention the codebase is legacy.

I came up with a workaround.

Since this operation is inside of a `Thread`.

`Thread.Sleep` could be another way for waiting one second, and you don't have to deal with timer.

Sorry, I can't comment it for less than 50 reputation.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to avoid Thread.Sleep and introduce timer.

Comment: Opps, then I shall remove this post.

Comment: By the way, why do you want to avoid Thread.Sleep?

Comment: The thread on which the code will execute already has a lot of code i.e it is being executed from a very big function....in order to not mess up and not to introduce any unexpected devil for me I would prefer a notification based waiting

Comment: If it's a thread, no matter how you implement your wait, you still have to pending this thread for one second. Am I missing any of your prerequisite? Is there a way to run many tasks on single thread?

Comment: @LouisGo: A thread is a worker, tasks are, well, tasks. One worker can switch between tasks when the current task stalls (i.e. awaits something). Think of it like a chef in a kitchen. A chef works on dish A, and there are multiple dishes that need to be made. The chef is working alone (= single thread) When dish A is put in the oven for 20 minutes, the chef is free to start working on dish B. So when you say "run many tasks on single thread", the answer is **yes, alternating but not simultaneous**.

Comment: @Flater that's only possible when you are using a thread from Threadpool or TaskParallelLibrary.

Comment: @NavjotSingh: As opposed to? If you use notification-based events (such as the timer), then you're going to want to rely on a separate thread to handle the notifications, no?

Comment: @Flater yeah agree, but when we do Thread.Sleep we make the thread not reusable.

Comment: I know Flater's point, but `Thread.Sleep` is making cpu switching to other thread so current task won't hold the resource of a threaded. That is, using timer+AutoResetEvent is same as Thread.Sleep if you just want to release cpu cycle for a certain time. Am I wrong?  I lookup at this article https://stackoverflow.com/a/2999128/4123703

Comment: Uh, I saw Flater's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, if you have a static instance of a class, and exit the application, the destructor for the class will be called, possibly while the static instance is still running other code, with possibly fatal results.

I would avoid static instances especially when timers or anything multithreaded is involved.